# How to populate multiple drop down boxes with mysql/php using different table columns

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT: Having issues with extra " or some sort of syntax when adding second select clause.

So im working on a php project using the mysql adventureworks sample database. Currently this page takes in an employees title which you can select from using the drop down box filled with all the possible titles to filter through the employees. However i wanted to add a second box with gender so someone could filter through a title and gender and get all the possible employees.

I have a tried a few things but they usually end up crashing the page.

Heres the first file: search.php

```
<?php
   // Connect to the database

   if (!include('connect.php')) {
      die('error finding connect file');
   }

   $dbh = ConnectDB();
?>
<html>

<head>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth" 
rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" 
rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <title>Table Results</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="content">

<h1>Search Adventureworks Employees</h1>
<p>Select two parameters and search information from the
AdventureWorks Database.</p>

<div class="form">
<form action="listTable.php" method="get">

<?php

   // Get the full list of titles from Employee Table
  $sql =  "SELECT Distinct title FROM adventureworks.employee";
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();

 // Prep drop down control
  echo "<label for='title'>Select title: </label>\n";
  echo "<select id='title' name='title'>\n";

 // Put titles in the options
  foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $titles) {
     echo "<option value='" . $titles['title'] . "'>" .
$titles['title'] . "</option>\n";
  }
   // End dropdown
  echo "</select>";

  // Get the full list of genders from employee table
  $sql3 = "Select Distinct gender FROM adventureworks.employee";
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql3);
  $stmt->execute();

  //Prep dropdown
  echo "<label for ='gender'>Select Gender: </label>\n";
  echo "<select id='gender' name = 'gender'>\n";

  // Put genders in the options
  foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $genders) {
     echo "<option value ='" . $genders['gender'] . "'> .
$genders['gender'] . "</option>\n";
   }
  //end dropdown and submit
  echo "</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='submit' 
value='Submit'>\n</form>\n</div>";
?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And heres the second php file: listTable.php

```
<?php
   // Connect to the database

   if (!include('connect.php')) {
      die('error finding connect file');
   }

   $dbh = ConnectDB();
?>
<html>

<head><link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth" 
rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono" 
rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <title>Table Results</title>
</head>

 <body>
 <div class='content'>

<?php
 // Get table name from querystring
    if (!isset($_GET["title"])) {
      echo "No Title Selected";
    }
   else {

      $title=$_GET["title"];
      echo "<h1>Listing of Employees</h1>\n";

      $sql1 = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns ";
      $sql1 .= "WHERE table_name = 'employee'";
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
      $stmt->execute();
      $cols = $stmt->rowCount();

  // Prep table
  $tableHTML = "<table>\n<thead>\n<tr>\n";

  // Table headings (column names)
  foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $columns) {
     $tableHTML .= "<th>" . $columns['column_name'] . "</th>\n";
  }

  // Prep table body
  $tableHTML .= "</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n";

  // Table body (column values)
  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM adventureworks.employee e";
  $sql2 .= " Where title like '$title'";
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql2);
  $stmt->execute();
  echo $stmt->rowCount() . " rows retrieved<br/><br />\n";

  foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $rows ) {
     $tableHTML .= "<tr>\n";
     for ($i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++) {
        $tableHTML .= "<td>" . $rows[$i] . "</td>\n";
     }
     $tableHTML .= "</tr>\n";
  }

  // End table
  $tableHTML .= "</tbody>\n</table>\n";
  echo $tableHTML;
  echo "<div class='code'><br />" . $sql1 . "<p>" . $sql2 . "</div>\n";
 } 
?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand what I would have to change in the second file in order to get the results I want but im having trouble just populating the second drop down in the first file.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the titles-list have an id? Making a second <select with the genders should not be the problem. you need to pass these two values via get or session to the other page. You can check, if you receive all get-values by using print_r($_GET);

Comment: @Bernhard the get area isnt my issue im just not sure where to start the second select statement without getting syntactical errors.

Comment: between /select> and &nbsp; Keep in mind that you need to escape additional "

Comment: @Bernhard i edited it to how it is now with a second select statement. I understand what your saying about the additional " but i dont really know where to fix it in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed a double quote in search.php

```
// Put genders in the options
  foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $genders) {
     echo "<option value ='" . $genders['gender'] . "'>" .
    $genders['gender'] . "</option>\n";
   }
```

Comment: Cant believe i missed that. Thanks so much!